# How to append input type submit elements on table using Jquery and bind it?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to append a table row which has a form and input type submit. Typically, this is what my loop looks like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User"))
          {
              <tr>
                  <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@item.Id" />
                  <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Email, new { name = "Email" })
                  </td>
                  
                     <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { Id = item.Id })">Edit</a>
                      <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Disable this?');" name="btnDisable" id="btnDisable">Disable</button>
                  </td>
             </tr>
          }
    }
```

Now on my AJAX call, I need to add additional user here on this table row, here's how I usually do it:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'URL',
        dataType: 'json'
       }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.status == 'True') {
            var usrObj = data.uobj;

            $(function () {
            var table = $('#tblUsers tbody');

            for (var i = 0; i < usrObj.length; i++) {
                $('#tblUsers').find('tbody')
                    .append('<tr><form action="/User/Edit" method="post">' +
                     '<input type="hidden" name="Id" value=' + usrObj[i].Id + '>' +
                     '<td>' + usrObj[i].Email + '</td>' +
                     "<td><a href='" + "/User/Edit/" + usrObj[i].Id + "'" + "></i>Edit</a>" + 
                     `<button type='submit' name='btnDisable' id = 'btnDisable' onclick="return confirm('Disable this?')";>Disable</button></td>` +
                        '</form></tr>');
                }
            }                
    });
```

Now what is happening is that, the appended link is working fine since everything the link that is needed to function is already set on it's attributes:

```
<a href='" + "/UserM/Edit/" + usrObj[i].Id + "'" + "></i>Edit</a>
```

This is I am having a hard time submitting the form:

```
<button type='submit' name='btnDisable' id = 'btnDisable' onclick="return confirm('Disable this?')";>Disable</button>
```

I tried adding the following code below but still, nothing is happening, the confirm dialog box is popping up, but upon clicking **Ok** button, nothing is happening. The form is not submitting. But the other rows are working fine after the append.

Here's what I tried, but all of these are not working fine.

```
  $(function () {
      $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (event) {
             $(this).submit();
          });
   });
```

I guess the way I appended my table row is the problem but I am not clearly sure.

Comment: HI, try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m4pwsqn2/) see if that works on your end .

Comment: @Swati I really appreciate your assistance, it works perfectly! If you want to post it as an answer, kindly do so so that I can mark it as the proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your current jquery code was that when you were appending new rows inside table it was going outside tr tag that's the reason form submit was not working . Instead you can put form tag inside *td* tag and the input field as well which you need to pass to backend so that form gets trigger using button inside it .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//this is for demo :)
var usrObj = [{
  "Email": "cdcdc",
  "Id": 11
}, {
  "Email": "cdcdc2",
  "Id": 12
}]
for (var i = 0; i < usrObj.length; i++) {
  $('#tblUsers').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + usrObj[i].Email + '</td>' + "<td><form action='/User/Edit' method='post'><a href='" + "/User/Edit/" + usrObj[i].Id + "'" + "></i>Edit</a>" + `<button type='submit' name='btnDisable' onclick="return confirm('Disable this?')";>Disable</button>` + '<input type="hidden" name="Id" value=' + usrObj[i].Id + '/></form>' + "</td></tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblUsers">
  <tbody>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="1" />
        <td>
          frg
        </td>
        <td>

          <a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", new { Id = item.Id })">Edit</a>
          <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Disable this?');" name="btnDisable" id="btnDisable">Disable</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="2" />
        <td>
          ckwlkev
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", new { Id = item.Id })">Edit</a>
          <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Disable this?');" name="btnDisable" id="btnDisable">Disable</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your ajax code with

```
for (var i = 0; i < usrObj.length; i++) {    
    $('#tblUsers').find('tbody').append('<tr><form action="/User/Edit" method="post">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="Id" value=' + usrObj[i].Id + '>' +
    '<td>' + usrObj[i].Email + '</td>' +
    '<td><a href="' + '/User/Edit/' + usrObj[i].Id + '"></i>Edit</a>' + 
    '<button type="submit" name="btnDisable" id = "btnDisable" onclick="return confirm(\'Disable this?\')";>Disable</button></td>' +
    '</form></tr>');
}
```

Also, `$(document).on` has much lower performance than `$('form.remember').on('submit')`. It now has to listen for all submit events in the document. It's much better to restrict the scope a little than listen on document, if possible